# Android : linkify the textview in android application

Tags: android

I am using linkify and I want to display "google" instead of "http://www.google.com" when I run the app plz any help

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    TextView textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Link1);
    textView.setText("http://www.google.com/");
    Linkify.addLinks(textView,Linkify.ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Html.fromHtml(String source)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)):

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"http://www.google.com/\">google</a>"));
```

Comment: it works but when I click on "google" nothing happen

Comment: Try removing `Linkify.addLinks(textView,Linkify.ALL);`